# cryptsetup: waiting for encrypted source device /swapfile

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, encryption, fstab

I know this has been asked but I am asking this because the fix i found didnt work.
I got the same problem this person had: [Ubuntu 19.04 "waiting for encrypted source device /swapfile" and then initramfs prompt on boot : linuxquestions](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/cerr1l/ubuntu_1904_waiting_for_encrypted_source_device/)

but i tried the fix which was to add "size=256" in /etc/crypttab.
I did that,  but it still warns me that I haven't specified size in crypttab and still takes time to boot. (my computer will still boot to a working gui if i type exit at the prompt)

Here's the contents of /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=694b4858-ead8-400d-9406-f9fc45dc71f1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=CA5F-286C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#/swapfile none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
#/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw,pri=100 0 0
```

and here is /etc/crypttab:

```
# <target name> <source device>     <key file>  <options>
cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256
```

does it help that it worked all the time before but just doesnt now, and that i had to use Ubuntu recovery mode DPKG before I edited /etc/crypttab?

Any help would be VERY appreciated. TY in advance!

edit: it would be nice if i could keep swap as i only have 5.7gb ram (2.3gb ram is system reserved)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to fix this.

1. Comment cryptswap related lines in `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab`
2. Execute `sudo swapoff -a && sudo update-initramfs -u`
3. If you want swap back, uncomment the lines you just commented
4. Reboot

However, although this works, I think this breaks for every new kernel update.

Answer (score 5):

The root cause and explanation, why above workaround works, is that initramfs cryptroot hook (`/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptroot`) is trying to translate `/swapfile` to block device when you have cryptswap in `/etc/crypttab`. This obviously fails as `/swapfile` is not a device and is not available during the time when initramfs runs.

As you are not using encrypted rootfs (otherwise `/swapfile` would be already encrypted as part of it) the easiest way is to disable this cryptroot hook. Unfortunately there is no nice way, how to do it. The best way I found was to insert `exit 0` into `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook` as this script is sourced by the cryptroot hook.

Comment: Adding `exit 0`as first statement to `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook` fixed this problem from re-appearing after every kernel update for me in Ubuntu 20.04